Does the author indicate who Daddy-long-legs is in the novel?
I read a simplified version of the novel "Daddy-Long-Legs". I understand that who Daddy-Long-Legs is at the end of the book. However the main character said when she met Daddy-Long-Legs for the first time,

In an instant it flashed over me. Oh, but I have been foolished. A
hundred little things might have told me, if I had had any wits.

Does the author indicate who Daddy-long-legs is in the novel? Is there a way to notice who Daddy-Long-Legs is in the middle of the novel?

"Daddy-Long-Legs" is Jervis Pendleton, Julia's uncle who asked Judy to marry him.   He reveals his identity after she refused him (as Jervis) and wrote to him (as Daddy-Long-Legs) saying she had done so because she was afraid that her past would cause trouble for him.

The reason I sent him away was not because I didn't care for him, but because I cared for him so much. I was afraid he would regret it in the future—and I couldn't stand that! It didn't seem right for a person of my lack of antecedents to marry into any such family as his. I never told him about the orphan asylum, and I hated to explain that I didn't know who I was. I may be dreadful, you know. And his family are proud—and I'm proud, too!

There are things that, in hindsight, are clues (such as his insisting on her going to the farm in the summer), but not enough to make it clear in advance.
